# Suppress runtime autolayout warnings in Xcode

Tags: ios, console, runtime, autolayout, warnings

I know the proper solution is to fix the autolayout issues or put in placeholder constraints but sometimes it would be very nice to have a way of simply blocking the runtime Autolayout warnings like with a build flag or piece of debug code leveraging the private API. Does anyone know how this might be possible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disable autolayout constraint error messages in debug console output in Xcode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31239934/disable-autolayout-constraint-error-messages-in-debug-console-output-in-xcode)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31239934/disable-autolayout-constraint-error-messages-in-debug-console-output-in-xcode

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable the "show warnings" in your xcodeproj.

Select your project -> Build Settings -> Interface Builder XIB Compiler - Options -> Show Warnings -> "NO"

Note: that will remove all your warnings from the interface builder.

Comment: What about the ones at runtime in the console?

Comment: I'm not sure you can. Did you find a way?

Comment: Nope :( I suspect there is a private API method you can override but I haven't tried anything yet